# How do I ground this metal switch faceplate? (UK electrical)

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light, uk

I'm replacing a plastic light switch with a metal one - so need to ground it.

Have done this before - where backbox has been metal, so easy to run a flywire from switch to grounding point on metal backbox.

However this time the backbox is plastic - so there's no grounding point.

See images below - do I just run a grounding flywire from the metal faceplate into the terminal block where all the unused grounding wires are currently?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: "do I just run a grounding flywire from the metal faceplate into the terminal block where all the unused grounding wires are currently?" - Yes.

Comment: "Passing through" is not the same as "unused".  People get nailed by that all the time with neutrals, they see a bundle of neutrals and unhook them all and just use one.  "Since they're spare".  This fails immediately.  The problem is, if you do that same thing with grounds, it will not fail immediately, and nothing will warn you that something is awry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do it if you have a differential breaker and/or the switch plate is double-insulated. If you haven't a differential look at the plate and see if there is a ground connector, if so ground to it.

Comment: Differential do you mean RCD (American: GFCI)?

Comment: Yes: a breaker that 'detects' that there's a difference between live and neutral. (IT: Interruttore differenziale, salvavita).